# access textfield text from another viewController

Tags: ios, swift, textfield, viewcontroller

I try to access a textfield content in my view `profileView` from my first view `viewController` but it doesn't work.
I read that I have to use `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {}` so I did but it still not working and I don't understand why.

Here is my `viewController` code:

```swift
// This code is the code generated by xCode, only the loginField was added.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loginField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

and here is my `profileController` prepare func:

```swift
    var login: String!
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        print("prepare")
        if (segue.identifier == "mainMenu")
        {
            let svc = segue.source as! ViewController
            login = svc.loginField.text
            self.myLabel.text = login
            print(login)
        }
    }
```

Actually, the thing i really read was "prepareForSegue" func but when I try to override it, xCode won't compile the code...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if your both vc in memory then use Protocol or Notification otherwise you can store it in userdefault and fetch whenever you need

Comment: What is the flow of your VC.??

Comment: @LeCintas. check out my answer and github link https://github.com/junaid4058/dataSending hope you will find it useful.

Comment: Check #Bala answer to get reason why you cannot pass data & check #elk answer how to pass data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

write your prepareforSegue method in your **viewController**

**why?**

Because you want to send **ViewController** textfield data to **profileViewController**.That is write your prepareForSegue in **Source**. Here,

```
Source = ViewController

Destination = ProfileView
```

Note:

1. Use a variable in your destinationViewController(**ProfileView Controller**) and keep the textField data in this variable.

like this in prepareForSegue.

```
 destinationVC.someVariable = self.SourceViewLabel.text // your sourceViewController
```

and in viewDidLoad of your **destinationViewController**(ProfileView) write this.

```
self.profileLabel.text = somVariable
```

In my first view i wrote this.

```
@IBAction func nexVCAction(_ sender: Any) {

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondvc", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier  == "secondvc" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! secondVC
        vc.stringHolder = textField.text!
    }

}
```

And this is the second view code.

```
import UIKit

class secondVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textlabel: UILabel!
    var stringHolder:String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textlabel.text = stringHolder

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

I made [git project](https://github.com/junaid4058/dataSending) for this.

Check only **FirstVC.swift** and **secondVC.swift**

And this is the output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the text of the `UITextField` and any other components of `UIKit` in the prepare for segue, because all `View` components of the recently allocated controller are not initialised yet they are all nil in `prepareForSegue`. they allocated only be when the viewController is presented.

You set Text for current `ViewController` `TextField` at `prepareForSegue`. Instead of this you should set text at `viewWillAppear` method while pop or dismiss the presented `ViewController` by using `Notification`, `Delegate` or `userDefaults` etc...

Comment: This is not answer of the question , Please update it with answer

Answer (score 0):

You just need a small fix since UITextField and any other components of UIKit are not initialised yet in the prepare for segue:

```
var login: String!

@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    print("prepare")
    if (segue.identifier == "mainMenu")
    {
        let svc = segue.source as! ViewController
        login = svc.loginField.text
        // self.myLabel.text = login
        print(login)
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.myLabel.text = login
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Data flow from one controller to another is the very popular theme for ios beginners. There are several approaches to achieve this goal: segues, delegate pattern, notifications, initialization of new instance of controller, saving data to local storage etc.

You should user `prepare(for segue: sender:)` method only when you have segue from you current controller to another. You can get access to destination controller instance via `destination` property of `segue` parameter.

Also never call `IBOutlet` properties of destination controller in `prepareForSegue` - it can be cause of crash, because Outlets may be uninitilized at this time. Instead use `String` property for example.

Here is sample code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "mainMenu") {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ViewController {
               destinationVC.login = self.myLabel.text
            }
        }
}
```

Where `login` in `destinationVC` is the String variable to store login.